# Tensorflow: Split a placeholder BEFORE input has been fed?

Tags: tensorflow

My model receives an input sequence via feed and then has to split this sequence by a delimiter within the model. However as Tensorflow's graph requires that we put placeholders before hand, I don't know how to make this work. The issue is that I don't know how many pieces the input sequence will be split into before I actually feed the input.

Is there a way to create a model that can handle a changing number and shape of tensors within the model?

Comment: Changing number can be done with a queue. Changing shape is harder -- space for queue buffers is allocated ahead of time, so it needs to know how big your tensors are. Maybe use queue and pad your inputs to same shape?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use an RNN?  If so, use parse_single_sequence_example to read data, in conjunction with a PaddingFIFOQueue, and dynamic_rnn to run the RNN on it.  You'll have to store your data as tensorflow.SequenceExample protos.  Alternatively you need a TF op that reads a string, splits on commas, and outputs a vector Tensor of values.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Eugene. One thing i'm  not clear on: can I still use the regular rnn (instead of dynamic_rnn), as long as my batch size is 1?

Comment: Not if your sequence lengths vary from example to example.  That said, dynamic_rnn is as fast as regular rnn and uses less memory; and we're thinking of deprecating the rnn() function at this point.